# Displaying a Google map in a BlackBerry WebWorks application

Tags: javascript, google-maps, blackberry, mobile, blackberry-webworks

I'm trying to display a Google map from within a WebWorks app. Here is the complete HTML of that page in the app (note that it works fine in the browser):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />

    <title>Waste Management Service Request</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        min-height: 500px;
      }
      .center {
        text-align: center;
      }
      #page {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 85%;
        width: 408px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 30px;
      }
      h3 {
        color: #006A3C;
      }
      #map-canvas {
        height: 300px;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

      if (typeof(blackberry) != "undefined") {
        blackberry.system.event.onHardwareKey(blackberry.system.event.KEY_BACK, function() {
          history.back(); 
        });
      }

      $(document).ready(function(){

        var geocoder, map;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        address = '100 1st St., New York City, NY'; // Hardcoded for testing.
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
          } else {
            alert("The map failed because: " + status);
          }
        });

      })
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="page">
      <h3>Local Map</h3>
      <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

From within the application, it just shows a gray box where the app should appear.

Note that the code is mostly yanked from the source of [this example page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple.html), which is linked to from [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html).

Any ideas? Is my best bet here to resort to having Google deliver static images rendered dynamically (i.e., [this technique](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)) or is there something I'm missing to get the real thing?

By the way, I tried to crawl through the JS call stack for gmaps and add each domain to the list of the app's permissions. I have permission entries (both http and https) for gmaptiles.co.kr, google.com, googleapis.com, and gstatic.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the Simulator are you using?  There was a [known issue](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/Playbook-Webworks-Javascript-amp-Jquery-problems/td-p/773353) in versions prior to 0.9.4 which caused problems when parameters were passed on the URL, and when accessing local files.  You could try linking to an external JQuery library to rule out the last point (don't forget to add `<access>` elements for it)?

Can you post the `<access>` elements you have defined in your config.xml?  I was wondering if you needed `subdomains="true"` or something like that?

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"/>
```

Other than that I suggest you keep stripping out content from the page until something appears, e.g. remove the `meta name="viewport"` line and go from there...

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with Google maps, and it runs fine using a BB browser version 6, but doesn't in 5 (the div is only gray). This with JQuery 1.5.1.

I use  for testing, the google maps also use another domains.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, just take care for config.xml file, providing access to the right domains, this works for me:

```
  <access subdomains="true" uri="http://gstatic.com"/>
  <access subdomains="true" uri="http://google.com"/>
  <access subdomains="true" uri="http://googleapis.com"/>
```

Finally, this only work on BB6...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got the answer to your problem I think! Try using JQuery 1.5 instead of 1.5.1. JQuery 1.5.1 seems to be broken in WebWorks for me which is pretty lame!

Comment: Another problem I just found.. The WebWorks system doesn't indicate requests that are ajax based in the headers, which broke my CakePHP system which detects ajax requests and returns the html without the <html><body> etc tags. Not fun debugging this stuff!

Answer (score -1):

set the map div z-index to 0 for BB OS 5